# Ember rest url not formatting as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple Ember Data RESTAdapter in use.

I am using a query for a record

```
return this.store.queryRecord('user', 5);
```

and for some reason this is translating to a uri

```
/Valid.George.WebApi/api/users?5
```

rather than

```
/Valid.George.WebApi/api/users/5
```

does anyone know of a setting that might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
return this.store.findRecord('user', 5);
```

Comment: yup... duh myself... realized that the queryRecord.. treats the parameters like url parameters. However now that I know this, I will have to see what it takes to at least name the parameters being called.